# core-plot padding for x axis

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

The code for my x-axis:

```
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
x.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 4;
```

I want to display 4 tick labels that are spread equally. This works, but the last label is only shown half. I could fix that by setting a paddingRight to the plotAreaFrame, but this would also make my chart smaller. Can I provide a padding only for the x axis?

Comment: Do you want the plot to extend all the way to the edge of the graph, but not the axis?

Answer (score 0):

The `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions` labeling policy always puts the outside tick marks at the edges of the plot area. Your options are to add padding to the plot area frame to make the plot area smaller so the labels can extend into the margin, or choose another labeling policy. `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval` (the default) would be a good choice.